# How to bind grid view in entity framework one to one relationship

Tags: c#, gridview, entity-framework-4

I want to know how to show data in grid view by using entity framework.  My table structure is

```
StudentId StudentName CourseId          
1       SS              1
2       AA              2


CourseId CourseName
1           English
2           Mathematics
```

Currently I can show Student id and name in grid view, but cant show CourseName.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
            Width="527px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentId" HeaderText="Model" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="StudentId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Costs" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="StudentName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=CarContext" DefaultContainerName="CarContext" 
            EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Cars" Select="it.[StudentId], it.[StudentName]">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
            Width="527px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentId" HeaderText="Model" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="StudentId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Costs" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="StudentName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="Course" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="CourseName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=CarContext" DefaultContainerName="CarContext" 
            EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Cars" Select="it.[StudentId], it.[StudentName],it.[CourseName]">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

and also edit the query of your EntityDataSource1, include CourseName to your query